# Why do 3D engines use rectangular projections for the camera perspective?

Tags: graphics

In most 3d applications, the scene is projected onto a rectangular area. As the field of view increases, you see terrible distortions near the edges of the screen. Why do modeling engines limit themselves to a projection matrix when they cannot produce reasonable perspectives above 90 degrees? Why are these engines not capable of having 180 or 360 degree fields of view for a panorama image?

I ask because I game with three screens and I recently have been manipulating some opengl code, and the question has always driven me crazy.

Comment: Unless you feel there might be some fundamental limit involved, this seems to be a question about implementation decisions by specific, unstated, pieces of software.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be careful what you mean by "3D applications".

Most high-end batch rendering systems (e.g. the sort that are used for feature animation and visual effects) do have pluggable camera models. If you look around the graphics literature, you can easily find papers on these, like [A Realistic Camera Model for Computer Graphics](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~gfx/courses/2008/IntroGraphics/Readings/Kolb95.pdf). Camera models aren't just about projection, either. There's depth of field/bokeh effects and shutter effects to take into account, and these days there's also 3D stereoscopic rendering.

However, even in that scenario, these sophisticated camera models aren't often used at render time. If you need to simulate an anamorphic lens or panorama, the effect could be achieved by either rendering to a larger target or rendering to multiple cameras (e.g. in a hemicube or hemicuboid pattern) and then performing the camera projection as a post-processing effect using image resampling techniques. This has the added advantage that the camera settings can be adjusted in real-time by an artist without having to recompute the whole image.

Incidentally, there is a similar thing with video games. Game designers may make an artistic decision to simulate a cinematic lens, but there's also a bunch of other dynamic distortion-like effects which may be required (e.g. simulating water splash on the camera), and anamorphic output devices such as the Oculus Rift. Given that you have to do different image-space effects anyway, doing camera lens effects in image-space just makes sense.

So it's fair to say that most camera transforms are performed in [projective space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space). The chief reason why is that projective space has one extremely convenient property: straight lines in Euclidean space map to straight lines in the corresponding projective space. (It's also the case that conic sections map to conic sections, which is the reason why projective space was first studied, but that's another story.)

This simplifies things enormously, both in software and in hardware. Complex geometry is typically tessellated into polygons for the purpose of sampling, because we know how to sample polygons efficiently. Polygon edges are straight lines. If they remain straight lines after the camera projection, then everything we know about sampling polygons still works in the obvious way.